# How to pass date time to a stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

```
string _name = txtName.Text;
string _addr = txtAddr.Text;
DateTime _dof = DateTime.Parse(drpDate.SelectedValue + drpMonth.SelectedValue + drpYear.SelectedValue);
string _country = drpCountry.SelectedValue;
string _gender = rdiomf.SelectedValue;

using (SqlConnection conn = conMgr.GetDatabaseConnection())
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insertStudent",conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sName", _name);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sAddress", _addr);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sDob", _dof);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sCountry", _country);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sGender", _gender);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

The error says error in date. I get date using drop down boxes. How can I fix this? please help me. I'm new to stored procedures and asp.net

Comment: What is the type of the `@sDob` parameter? I'm guessing varchar (string) because of the prefix `s`. You should make that parameter into a `DateTime` type instead.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen my sDob parameter is DateTime type. not string

Comment: Some hints to debug this: On what line do you get the error, `DateTime.Parse` or `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`? What are the values of the dropdowns, what is the string that goes into `DateTime.Parse`, what is the value of `_dof` (if the code gets that far)?

Answer (score 4):

use new date time for this.

```
DateTime _dof = new DateTime(Convert.ToInt32(drpYear.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(drpMonth.SelectedValue), Convert.ToInt32(drpDate.SelectedValue));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not a good idea to use three drop downs to construct the date. it is very hard to handle the validation. (e.g. is Feb 30 2013 a valid date??) Use the .net build in Patetimepicker instead. that is all handled by the framework. If it is client side, use JQuery plugin.

And then you can simply pass that dateTimePicker1.Value to the store procedure parameter.

It will be easier for you.

Answer (score 1):

The way you are doing it you are trying to convert let's say `010213` this is the format you are trying to convert which will fetch `String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`error. Use `-` to differentiate between months and years.

```
DateTime _dof = Convert.toDateTime(drpDate.SelectedValue +"-"+ drpMonth.SelectedValue +"-"+drpYear.SelectedValue);
```

OR use this overload.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can user jquery datepicker instead of three dropdown..

```
         <html lang="en">
      <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8" />
           <title>jQuery UI Datepicker - Default functionality</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
            <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css" />
                 <script>
                  $(function() {
                  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
                  });
               </script>
           </head>
           <body>
            <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
         </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your dropdown values as below:-

string _datetime=drpMonth.SelectedValue+drpDate.SelectedValue+drpYear.SelectedValue

Datetime _dof = Convert.ToDateTime(_datetime);